# Ignoring specific patterns on a page when using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am using `sed` to find and replace some items in a document:

```
        sed -i "0,\/^$a/s//$b/" ./file
```

This is used to replace words, e.g.: replace "lion" with "animal".

```
I saw the lions at the zoo.
```

This is changed to:

```
I saw the animals at the zoo.
```

Within the document, there are some components mixed within the text, which I want `sed` to completely ignore. These take the form of `\macro{text}`, e.g.:

```
I saw the li\footnote{Hello.}ons at the zoo.
```

As the area `\footnote{Hello.}` this still must be changed to:

```
I saw the animals at the zoo.
```

These all begin with `\` and ending with `}`, but never use more than one `}` and no other `\` or `}`. are used in other places within the file.

- How can I get `sed` to ignore these?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo "I saw the li\footnote{Hello.}ons at the zoo." | 
sed 'h;s/\\[^}]*}//g;/'"$a"'/!{g;b};s//'"$b"'/g;'
```

- This saves the current line in the hold space
- Removes macro calls
- If `$a`  does not exist it returns the original line otherwise it replaces `$a` with `$b`

N.B. This assumes no lines with mixed macros

Comment: What is a line with a mixed macro?